# C++ Windows API MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN, MOUSEEVENTF_XUP don't work

Tags: c++, windows

I was trying to learn to use the c++ Windows API to send mouse input to windows and it's been great so far but for some reason when I try to use a `mouseInput` structure with `dwflags` set to `(MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_XUP)` it doesn't seem to do anything, all the other dwFlags seem to work as well,
In the documentation it is said that when `MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN` (or `MOUSEEVENTF_XUP`) are used as `dwFlags` it should invoke the press or release on the button stored in `mouseData` (`XBUTTON1` for example) but it doesn't seem to do anything, Is something wrong with the code? or am I not using it properly?
I'm using windows 10 64x

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>


void clickMouse()
{
    INPUT event;
    MOUSEINPUT mouseInput = 
{
    0,
    0,
    XBUTTON1,
    (MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_XUP),
    0,
    NULL
};
event.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
event.mi = mouseInput;
SendInput(1, &event, sizeof(INPUT));

}

int main()
{
bool buttonPressed = false;
while (true)
{
    if (!buttonPressed && (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) >> 15))
    {
        clickMouse();
        buttonPressed = true;
    }
    else if (buttonPressed && !(GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) >> 15))
    {
        buttonPressed = false;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Did you check the return value of `SendInput`? Does it report success or failure?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is meaningful to combine the MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN event and the MOUSEEVENTF_XUP event. It would appear more meaningful to first send the DOWN event and then the UP event.

Comment: It appears you are sending a click event at the coordinates (0,0) relative to the position of the last mouse click. Is this intentional? Wouldn't absolute coordinates be more appropriate, for example (100,100) if the target window is in the top-left corner? For absolute coordinates, you must set the MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE flag.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Success (non zero value)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I'm not trying to move the mouse, Shouldn't coordinates (0, 0) relative to the last reported position be suitable for that?

Comment: Yes, relative coordinates are appropriate for what you describe.

Answer (score 2):

I made a minor change to your code (pointed out by Andreas) to fire the events sequentially as a real user would do. I used Chrome for a target by positioning the mouse anywhere over the window. It appears, at least on my machine, the WM_XBUTTONDOWN followed by the WM_XBUTTONUP message activates the back button regardless of where the mouse is positioned. I also used Spy++ to verify that these are the messages being generated. With 0,0 specified it fires the event at the last known mouse position. Because this is an X button you have to find an application that responds to that event to seen that it is working or use Spy++ or similar tool to see that it is firing. Here is the code I used.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>


void clickMouse()
{
    INPUT event;
    MOUSEINPUT mouseInput[] =
{  
    {
    0,
    0,
    XBUTTON1,
    (MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN),
    0,
    NULL
},
{
    0,
    0,
    XBUTTON1,
    (MOUSEEVENTF_XUP),
    0,
    NULL
}};
event.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
event.mi = mouseInput[0];
SendInput(1, &event, sizeof(INPUT));
event.mi = mouseInput[1];
SendInput(1, &event, sizeof(INPUT));
}

int main()
{
    bool buttonPressed = false;
    while (true)
    {
        if (!buttonPressed && (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) >> 15))
    {
        clickMouse();
        buttonPressed = true;
    }
    else if (buttonPressed && !(GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) >> 15))
    {
        buttonPressed = false;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm doing and it works. The key is to use `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` and  `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP` instead of `MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN` and `MOUSEEVENTF_XUP`:

```
void MouseInput(int x, int y, int button, bool release)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    INPUT input;
    input.type         = INPUT_MOUSE;
    input.mi.mouseData = button;
    input.mi.dx        = int(x * (65536.0f / GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)));
    input.mi.dy        = int(y * (65536.0f / GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)));
    input.mi.dwFlags   = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | (button ? (release ? MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP : MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN) : 0);
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
#endif // _WIN32
}
```

Example call:

```
{
    MouseInput(500, 200, 0, false); // just move the mouse
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));
    MouseInput(500, 200, 1, false); // push the left button
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(150));
    MouseInput(500, 200, 1, true); // release the left button
}
```